# Проверить на существование таблицу в PostgreSQL

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

Здесь больше  вопрос на то, как организовать проверку на то, что данная таблица существует или нет. Есть две функции. Первая сохранить элемент в БД:

```py
def save_in_db(macAddress, topic, payload):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname=DB_DATABASE,user= DB_USERNAME,password= DB_PASSWORD)
    exist_table = table_exists(conn, "stat"+macAddress)
    if exist_table == False:
        create_table_enhet(conn, macAddress)
    try:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO stat" + macAddress + " (topic, message, ts) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)", (topic, payload ,datetime.now(),))
        conn.commit()
        cur.close()
        conn.close()
    except psycopg2.Error as e:
        logger.error("save_in_db",e)
```

и вторая, которая проверяет на существование и вызывается из первой:

```py
def table_exists(conn, table_name):
    exists = False
    try:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("select exists(select relname from pg_class where relname='" + table_name + "')")
        exists = cur.fetchone()[0]
        cur.close()
        return exists
    except psycopg2.Error as e:
        logger.error ("table_exists", e)
```

Существуют такие ситуации, которые создают конфликт в `connect`-сущности. То есть временами выпадает ошибка

> current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

Насколько верно передавать `connect`-объект для проверки на существование? Или лучше в функции `table_exists()` создать свой `connect`, а после проверки закрыть и создать новый объект `connect` для манипуляций в `save_in_db()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка:

> current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of
> transaction block

обычно возникает когда вы пытаетесь выполнить SQL команду сразу после ошибки, произошедшей в той же DB сессии. [Здесь подробнее...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2979389/5741205)

Поэтому эту ошибку следует обработать и сделать `ROLLBACK` в конце.

---

По поводу передачи `conn` как параметра - я бы именно так и делал, вместо того, чтобы каждый раз создавать новую DB сессию - это слишком накладно.

Еще я бы немного переписал вашу функцию `table_exists()`:

```
def table_exists(conn, table_name):
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute("select exists(select 1 from information_schema.tables where table_name=%s)", 
                    [table_name])
        return True if cur.fetchone() else False
```

использование:

```
if not table_exists(conn, "stat"+macAddress):
        create_table_enhet(...)
```

Comment: Курсор не закрывать перед `return`?

Comment: @Dmitry, "good point!" - немного исправил ответ)

Comment: Все работает, все прекрасно, пока...) Одно только: обработка исключений в `table_exists()` специально пропущена или это само собой разумеющееся и она должна там присутствовать? Можно односложно, дальше сам разберу

Comment: @Dmitry, я просто не очень себе представляю какие исключения и как тут можно обрабатывать... Если `conn` - это активное соединение с PostgreSQL базой, а `table_name` - строка - все должно работать.

Answer (score 1):

Дополню ответ от @MaxU насчет, когда стоит создавать `connect`-сущность, когда `cursor`. Информация с офф доки [Best practices](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/faq.html#best-practices)

1. Когда следует сохранять и повторно использовать `cursor`, а не создавать новый по мере необходимости?
   `cursor` - легковесные объекты, и их создание в большом количестве не должно вызывать никаких проблем. Предпочтение состоит в том, что создавать почти всегда новую сущность и удалять старые, как только данные перестают быть нужными.
2. Когда следует сохранять и повторно использовать `connect`, а не создавать новый по мере необходимости?
   Создание соединения может быть медленным, поэтому лучше всего создать одно соединение и держать его открытым столько времени сколько необходимо. Так же `best practice` является частый откат (`rollback`, который упомянут @MaxU), чтобы быть увереным, что backend никогда не остается в [`idle in transaction`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/monitoring-ps.html). Состояние, когда транзакция открыта и простаивает.

Comment: отличное дополнение - жаль я только сейчас его увидел)